# How to click brower prompt in casperjs

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs, confirm, browser-automation

I am creating a automated script to do a testing. So when my script try to log out by clicking  "log out" it prompt confirmation window where the script has to select 'ok'

```
Source page looks likes: 

<script type="text/javascript">
        function logOut() {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to log out of the system?\nClick OK for Yes or CANCEL for No"))
                location.href='ppp_logout.cfm'
        }</scrip

My code to click log out and filter the confirm box.

casper.clickLabel('Log Out', 'a');
        casper.echo('------$$$ Log Off button clicked', 'INFO');
        casper.setFilter('page.confirm', function(msg){
            return msg === "Are you sure you want to log out of the system?\nClick OK for Yes or CANCEL for No" ? false : true;
        });



reference: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/1.1-beta2/events-filters.html
Allows to react on a javascript confirm() call:

casper.setFilter("page.confirm", function(msg) {
    return msg === "Do you like vbscript?" ? false : true;
});


what I am doing wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Your ternary operation is backwards.

You can change the following line:

```
return msg === '...' ? false : true;
```

... to:

```
return msg === '...' ? true : false;
```

... but since the ternary operation is not needed, you can simply write:

```
return msg === '...';
```

---

#### Full Example:

Consider the following HTML container:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Now, contemplate the following JavaScript code on the same page:

```
var result = document.getElementById('result');

if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
  result.textContent = 'Success!';
}
```

You can use the following CasperJS code to obtain the result:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.setFilter('page.confirm', function (message) {
  return message === 'Are you sure?';
});

casper.start('https://example.com/', function () {
  this.echo(this.getElementInfo('#result').text);  // Result: 'Success!'
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I have overlooked the logic. Now I have updated my code (? true : false)but I am not sure even with the wrong logic I have able to log off from the portal and navigate to the home page. Thanks again, I am going to look at my code again to find out the reason.